# use solidity function in react

Tags: reactjs, function, solidity

I have a solidity function to add data
so I wanna create some textbox and a button in react to add the textbox data to blockchain

there is my solidity code

```
  pragma solidity 0.6.4;
contract Storage{    
    uint [] public ids;
    string [] public activityNames;
    string [] public authorNames;
    string [] public activityTypes;
    
    function add(uint id, string memory activityName, string memory authorName, string memory activityType) public {
        ids.push(id);
        activityNames.push(activityName);
        authorNames.push(authorName);
        activityTypes.push(activityType);
    }
```

and this is my react set handler code but only adds one value
So I wanna make the set handler add all the 4 values not only one

```
    const setHandler = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        contract.add(event.target.setText.value);
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your contract signature is expecting 4 values but you are only passing a single one in when you call it, fill out the rest of the values expected and it should work.

Comment: I wanna to add 4 values but i don’t know how to make the sethandler to add all the 4 values as you see its only add one value not 4 , thanks